# How to reshape pandas dataframe with pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

```
    Year  Start  End   Name       Price
0   nan   0101   0331  Squirtle    876
1  2021   0101   1231  Squirtle    200
2   nan   0101   0331  Wartortle   1000
3  2021   0101   1231  Wartortle   1200
4   nan   0101   0331  Blastoise   3100
5  2021   0101   1231  Blastoise   4200
6  2022   0101   1231  Blastoise   10000
```

I want to reshape it like this,

```
                   Name    Squirtle      Wartortle       Blastoise
Year  Start End
nan   0101  0331              876           1000            3100
2021  0101  1231              200           1200            4200
2022  0101  1231                                            10000
```

I tried,
`df.pivot(index=['Year', 'Start', 'End'], columns='Name', values='Price')`. But didn't get any luck.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Use `pivot_table` instead of `pivot` to get the grouping you want.  The only caveat is you will need to replace the `NA` values (if they are actually `NA` and not the string `'nan'`).

```py
df.fillna('NA').pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Start', 'End'], columns='Name', values='Price')
# returns:
Name               Blastoise  Squirtle  Wartortle
Year   Start End
2021.0 101   1231     4200.0     200.0     1200.0
2022.0 101   1231    10000.0       NaN        NaN
NA     101   331      3100.0     876.0     1000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['Year','Start','End','Name'])['Price'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Name               Blastoise  Squirtle  Wartortle
Year   Start End                                 
NaN    101   331      3100.0     876.0     1000.0
2021.0 101   1231     4200.0     200.0     1200.0
2022.0 101   1231    10000.0       NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mistakenly used `pivot` instead of `pivot_table`.

```
data = [[np.NaN, 101, 331, 'Squirtle', 876],
[2021, 101, 1231, 'Squirtle', 200],
[np.NaN, 101, 331, 'Wartortle', 1000],
[2021, 101, 1231, 'Wartortle', 1200],
[np.NaN, 101, 331, 'Blastoise', 3100],
[2021, 101, 1231, 'Blastoise', 4200],
[2022, 101, 1231, 'Blastoise', 10000]]

df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Start', 'End'], columns='Name', values='Price')
```

Outputs:

```
Name               Blastoise  Squirtle  Wartortle
Year   Start End                                 
2021.0 101   1231     4200.0     200.0     1200.0
2022.0 101   1231    10000.0       NaN        NaN
```

Whereas if you replace the values with a placeholder value such as 1000

```
df = df.fillna(1000)
df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Start', 'End'], columns='Name', values='Price')
```

You would get what you desire of:

```
Name               Blastoise  Squirtle  Wartortle
Year   Start End                                 
1000.0 101   331      3100.0     876.0     1000.0
2021.0 101   1231     4200.0     200.0     1200.0
2022.0 101   1231    10000.0       NaN        NaN
```